# A JS Memory Leak with nothing under comparison mode in the chrome dev profile pane

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a JS roller.All things go well except the increasing memory in the chrome memory manager.I realize there is a memory leak with my code.Also,I try hard to find the evil roots with the chrome dev tool.

Timeline:
[image]

I got this.OK,there is obvious memory leak going up and up.

After that,I try profile.
While the roller rolling,I take serveral snapshot and compare them.
Sometimes,I got this
[image]

But sometimes,I got this.
[image]

There is some (dependent code) in it,but I can't figure what it is.

Has anyone come across with this problem?I need your help.

The code is too long.So I write a short demo code for it.

```
Roller = function(){
    var _container, _curIndex, _timer;

    function init(container) {
        _container = container;
        _curIndex = 0;
    }

    function start() {
      _autoRoll();
    }

    function _autoRoll() {
      goNext();
      if (_timer) {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         timer = null;
      }
      setTimeout(arguments.callee, 500);
    }

    function goNext() {
      // do some stuff with container(the dom)
      // _curIndex used
    }

    return {
       init: init,
       start: start,
       goNext: goNext
    };
}();
var roller = Roller.init(document.getElementById("roller"));
roller.start()
```

Comment: `there is a memory leak with my code` - I see pretty pictures, but no code. Hard to guess, check line 37

Comment: @JaromandaX updated,thx~

Comment: My guess would be that the problem is hidden in "*do some stuff with container(the dom)*". The code you posted is fairly innocent.